# Why is volatile variable much more efficient than plain synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

I've been told that the use of a volatile variable is much more efficient than using a synchronized block whenever using it (read or write).

Up until Java 1.4 I can see why (because then threads didn't have to flush and refresh all accessible memory).

But since Java 1.5, the only difference I see between using volatile variable and a synchronized block - is the lock acquiring mechanism.

Is acquiring the lock really that expensive? And if so, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The "expense" is because of it reading from memory every time, instead of possibly using the memory caches. It is [not a lot, at least on x86 machines](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html).

Comment: But it reads from memory everytime also when using volatile on Java 1.5 and on, doesn't it?

Comment: The memory model was "broken" earlier: https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile

Comment: I still don't understand. To my understanding, as to visibility, synchronization and volatile are similar (on Java >= 1.5). So what differences remain between them except of lock acquiring? and if so, why is it expensive??

Comment: Another reason: Synchronization results in the flushing of the associated CPU cache whenever you acquire/release locks/monitors. volatile doesn't do that, since it isn't kept in the cache.

Comment: Under the new JMM, a write-read to-from a volatile variable, does cause a memory flush-reload. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/

Comment: Please read this: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/archive/ Especially the last part where they discuss volatile. Just search for "volatile" within that page, and read those threads.

Answer (score 1):

volatile variable and synchronization are different tools for synchronization.
Its not ideal to compare the performances of these too.

Volatile - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5
         - In a way it is there to address  issues like visibility of variable and reordering of instructions.

Synchronization - Its totally a different giant. It guarantees atomicity along with taking 
              care of reordering and visibility. In order to achieve Atomicity it has to do  lots of book keeping.

Therefore synchronization is expensive then read or write of a volatile variable.
To be fair you ought to compare different mechanism of synchronization and different type
of locks i.e ReaderWriterLock, StampedLock, also study about CompareAndSwap its a good read.